# ArrayObject in API Response along with status and message

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I want the API Response to be as Follows:

`{"success":"false/true","msg":"some message","data":{}}`

if there is data the response data should print in `"data":{}`

`ApiResponse Class`

```
public ApiResponse(Boolean success, String message,JSONObject data) {
       this.success = success;
       this.message = message;
       this.setData(data);
   }
```

Data Returning in `Controller`

```
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(user);
return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "User is Disabled",dataObject , HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can specify more details like what is the output you expect and what you are actually getting.

Comment: I'm getting `{"success":"true","msg":"User Created"}` but I want to get the created user object in the response like `{"success":"true","msg":"User Created","data":{/user object/}}`

Comment: If I add `User` in `ApiResponse` class it will get what I need but it will be specific to that particular `User` but I want to set  every **response object** in `data:{}`

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot would internally uses jackson objectmapper to serialize the object.

You can specify to include the fields even if they are null by using this property when you create the objectMapper bean

```
    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS) // Include even empty values in the json
            .build();
}
```